# How I Can boot Full Encrypted Distro Manually From grub> Minimal Bash?

Tags: bash, fedora, grub

I'm new here 
I've been using Fedora about year , and my question is that , i have installed Fedora on Encrypted Hard Disk with LVM 
and Here is my Volume Group

```
VG          #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
fedora_unix   1   4   0 wz--n- 47.04g 4.00m
```

and my Logical Volumes are

```
  LV   VG          Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  00   fedora_unix -wi-ao----  5.00g                                                    
  01   fedora_unix -wi-ao----  5.00g                                                    
  02   fedora_unix -wi-ao----  3.82g                                                    
  03   fedora_unix -wi-ao---- 33.21g
```

and The Result Of The lsblk  is

```
 NAME                                            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
 sda                                               8:0    0   50G  0 disk  
 ├─sda1                                            8:1    0  976M  0 part  /boot/efi
 ├─sda2                                            8:2    0    2G  0 part  /boot
 └─sda3                                            8:3    0   47G  0 part  
    ├─fedora_unix-03                              253:0    0 33.2G  0 lvm   
    │ └─luks-62a9d691-240c-49b9-b937-f611ef79b05c 253:2    0 33.2G  0 crypt /
    ├─fedora_unix-02                              253:1    0  3.8G  0 lvm   
    │ └─luks-79810c34-a63d-43b6-80db-297d7982d66e 253:3    0  3.8G  0 crypt [SWAP]
    ├─fedora_unix-00                              253:4    0    5G  0 lvm   
    │ └─luks-c49e658c-196a-4d07-8932-24e80fd36d79 253:7    0    5G  0 crypt /home
    └─fedora_unix-01                              253:5    0    5G  0 lvm   
      └─luks-9e434ce7-2686-4f3f-9d55-b90224a1c290 253:6    0    5G  0 crypt /var

      sr0                                              11:0    1 55.3M  0 rom
```

So How to define The root directory In grub > Minimal Bash ?

when i write

```
grub> ls

(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (lvm/fedora_unix-03)

(lvm/fedora_unix-02) (lvm/fedora_unix-01) (lvm/fedora_unix-00)


grub> set root=(hd1,gpt2)

grub> linuxefi /vmlinuz-4.17.2-200.fc28.x86_64  root=/dev/mapper/fedora_unix-03

grub> initrdefi /initramfs-4.17.2-200.fc28.x86_64.img

grub> boot
```

It does not boot , it just ask for the passpharse and  after that the system could not switch to the real root file system

In Fact I can Boot an Encrypted Ubuntu , because the root file system is defined as

```
root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

But In My Case , In Fedora , I Tried

```
root=/dev/mapper/fedora_unix-root
```

It Does Not work

I also tried

```
root=/dev/mapper/fedora_unix-03
```

and it doest work also

Answer (score 1):

On my non-luks lvm setup with this schema

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 978.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1           8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2           8:2    0 977.9G  0 part 
  ├─vtb-Kali   253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vtb-Bunsen 253:1    0    10G  0 lvm  
  ├─vtb-Home   253:2    0   200G  0 lvm  /home
  └─vtb-Work   253:3    0   300G  0 lvm  /home/bu5hman/Documents/work
```

My GRUB boot sequence for those joyous occasions when the `GRUB` goes splat is

```
set root=(/lvm/vtb-Kali)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/mapper/vtb-Kali
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

From this it seems you are pointing `set root` at the wrong partition.

Making a leap of faith to Fedora for setting the root to the `/` on your lvm and leaving fstab to pick up `/boot/efi` I would suggest you try

```
set root=(/lvm/fedora_unix-03)
linuxefi  /vmlinuz-4.17.2-200.fc28.x86_64  root=/dev/mapper/fedora_unix-03
initrdefi /initramfs-4.17.2-200.fc28.x86_64.img
boot
```

If that doesn't work then try it without the leading `/` in `set root`

```
set root=(lvm/fedora_unix-03)
```

EDIT: after discussion in comments

try

```
`set root=`  with either of the 2 options in my previous post.
```

After your call to linuxefi use

```
root=/dev/mapper/luks-d2c9decd-e486-4ef3-9146-654ca2b4ec0a
```

Comment: Thanks Sir , But For Sorry It does not work

Here is my /etc/fstab